# How to dynamically access object property in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, oop

The thing that I'm trying to do should be simple but I'm not sure how to exactly do it.

**Problem Statement -**

We have an array : `static List<String> dataToShow = ['open', 'high', 'low', 'last', 'volume'];`

& some code : `valFetched = dataToShow[index];`

and a GridTile:

```
GridTile(
 header: Text(valFetched),
 child: Text(DataModel.??) //What should come here
);
```

& this DataModel:

```
class DataModel {
  final String last;
  final String high;
  final String low;
  final String volume;
  final double open;
  ...other props here...
}
```

Now as you can see that our class DataModel has the properties that I've put inside the array. I just want the value of those properties to be fetched from within the DataModel object `DataModel.valueOf(valFetched)`

EDIT : Adding future builder to demonstrate the use case

```
return FutureBuilder<DataModel>(
                    future: cache.data![ackw.data],
                    builder:
                        (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DataModel> data) {
                      if (!data.hasData) {
                        return const Text('Loading ..');
                      }
                      return ListView(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        children: [
                          ListTile(
                            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: cDefaultPadding),
                            dense: true,
                            title: Text(
                              ackw.data!.toUpperCase(),
                              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 38),
                            ),
                            trailing: Text(DateFormat.yMMMMd('en_US')
                                .add_jms()
                                .format(data.data!.timestamp)),
                          ),
                          GridView.builder(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(cDefaultPadding),
                            itemCount: DataConstants.dataToShow.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              String valFetched =
                                  DataConstants.dataToShow[index];
                              return GridTile(
                                  header: Text(valFetched),
                                  child: Text(data.data.valFetched));
                            }, gridDelegate: null,
                          )
                        ],
                      );
                    });
```

As you can see data.data.valFetched produces an error because it tries to access valFetched property from data.data whereas what I want to do is data.data.valueInsideValFetched

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full code of how to call a list of strings over the model class:

1. Declare a List of Strings.
2. Create model class based on list properties
3. Store data in `List<Model>`
4. Call model class over the `listView`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
// declare list 
  List<String> dataToShow = ['open', 'high', 'low', 'last', 'volume'];
// declare List of data model
  List<DataModel> data = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
// store list data in  list model
    for (var item in dataToShow) {
      data.add(DataModel(item));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap:true,
          itemCount: data.length,
          itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
           //DataModel object DataModel.valueOf(valFetched)
            return GridTile(child: Text(data[index].title));
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
// model class
class DataModel {
  String title;
  DataModel(this.title);
}
```

And also follow the dartpad [link](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/?id=688047457a1dd8c0c44e4c42c48a8a24)

Comment: Thanks for replying. The problem is that data cannot be a List of DataModel. 0bject of DataModel is a future that comes from a stream. It is an object with the properties (new,last,bid...etc. etc.) Instead of doing object.new , object.last...and so on for every value in that object, I just wanted to create this array so that only these values are fetched from this object and that too without us writing them all down one by one (considering this is a builder). Is that possible ?

Comment: yes it is possible, you can write from list directly and as well as use enum value

Comment: Even if I use an enum, object will never accept it as It wouldn't be one if it's properties. Considering an Object that has two props. Lets say first and second. Now instead of doing - Object.first , i want this first to fetched from an array, considering, array is ['first', 'second']. SO it would be like Object.valueOfFirstElementFromArray

Comment: yes, you are right. But it would be helpful if you share your steam code part.

Comment: I've just added that. Please check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240215/discussion-between-jahidul-islam-and-divyam-dhadwal).